# styleOverrides behaviour is different in MUI v4 and v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to migrate MUI from v4 to v5, I've been facing a different behaviour with the the `overrides`.

To explain the problem well, I've created 2 codesandbox with minimal code in both v4 and v5 versions.

In this [MUI v4](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-v4-overrides-zx9whr?file=%2Findex.js%3A20%2C37) example, overrides are only applied for the button which has no color defined. Primary button is working as expected. This is the desired behaviour

But in [MUI v5](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-v5-ovverides-hfhzh7?file=%2Findex.js%3A15%2C35) example, both the buttons are getting override values regardless of `color` defined or not.

This is a minimal example but due to this, my whole theme is messed up. Any clues what this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v5 the default value for the `Button` color prop changed from `default` to `primary`. So in v5 the following two buttons are identical (apart from the text in them):

```
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Primary</Button>
    <Button variant="contained">Grey</Button>
```

The easiest way I see to get back to the v4 behavior is to use `color="inherit"` for the buttons that were previously using `color="default"` (either explicitly or implicitly via absence of the color prop) and change your style overrides to target `containedInherit` instead of `contained`.

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  StyledEngineProvider,
  createTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@mui/material/styles";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        containedInherit: {
          backgroundColor: "grey",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Primary
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="inherit">
        Grey
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

[image: Edit Mui v5 ovverides (forked)]

Related documentation:

- https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#%E2%9C%85-remove-default-color-prop

Comment: Understandable about the `Button` but what about the other elements? Seems like overrides are not respecting the component's props at all and giving priority to overrides. I've updated the example for v4 and v5 and added a button. In v4, it still respects the if `IconButton` has a size prop and applies the padding respectively but in v5, it just applies the padding from the overrides

Comment: For `IconButton`, the v5 behavior seems like an improvement. Your padding change was being applied to `root`, so there isn't any good reason why it should apply to `size="small"` differently than any other size. If you only want it to apply to the medium size, then you can target `sizeMedium` instead of `root` (https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-v5-ovverides-forked-4t2q3q?file=%2Findex.js%3A11%2C1).